# Boost (1.57) GIL gives a compilation error "Non-type template argument evaluates to -1" in channel_algorithm.hpp

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, clang, boost-gil

We are using Boost 1.57 in our project. We are now interested in using GIL to write image files.

To `#include <boost/gil/gil_all.hpp>` in a translation unit raises the following error with Clang [*Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)*].

```
boost/gil/channel_algorithm.hpp:54:85:
    error: non-type template argument evaluates to -1,
           which cannot be narrowed to type 'unsigned long'
```

- Also surprising is that by searching the web for this error, it seems that it should have been fixed some versions ago, by [ticket 7970](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7970).
- Plus, [the incriminated definition](https://github.com/MatthewBooth/boost/blob/master/gil/channel_algorithm.hpp#L53-L54) seems to still be present on master.

Does anyone know the status of this ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with clang-3.6 and Boost 1.57/58/59. Neither with GCC. So I'm assuming a compiler bug was fixed since 3.4